# Divisibility theory help

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> If $a$ is odd, show that $32 \mid (a^2 + 3)(a^2 + 7)$

Since $a$ is odd, I let $a = 2b + 1$ and did the expansion to get $16\mid [(b^2 + b +1)(b^2 + b + 2)]$, but I was unable to continue from here. Is it the correct method ?

Can someone also please teach me how to show that

$3 \mid a(2a^2 + 7) $

for any arbitrary integer $a$?

Comment: It follows from the fact that $(b^2+b+1)(b^2+b+2)$ is even (why?)

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: $(k+1)(k+2)$ is always even. Now take $k=b^2+b$.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel Is that derived from an even number multiplied by a odd number equals an even number ? It works by substituting numbers but how can we prove that ?

Answer (score 2):

$$(a^2+3)(a^2+7)=(a^2-1+4)(a^2-1+8)=\{(a-1)(a+1)\}^2+12(a-1)(a+1)+32$$

Now as $a$ is odd, one of $a-1,a+1$ is divisible by $4$ and the other is by $2,$ not by $4$

$\implies 4\cdot2$ divides $(a-1)(a+1)$

Comment: But how to show the entire statement is divisible by 32?

Comment: @GuoJinLong, If $8|(a-1)(a+1),8^2|\{(a-1)(a+1)\}^2; 12\cdot8| 12(a-1)(a+1)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
Consider the congruence class of $a^2+3$ modulo $4$ and the congruence class of $a^2+7$ modulo $8$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $a$ is odd, then $a^2=8m+1$.

Proof: Let $a=4k\pm 1$. Then $(4k\pm 1)^2=16k^2\pm 8k+1$.

For the second one: if $a$ is divisible by $3$, we're done.

Otherwise $2(3k\pm 1)^2+7=18k^2\pm12k+9$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your solution

Comment: I didn't understand it.  What does with $2(3k\pm1)+7$ refers to ?

Comment: @Lærne If $a$ is not divisible by $3$, then $a=3k\pm 1$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I got that.  I didn't got why there was a factor $2$ all of a sudden. $2a^2 + 7$ vs $a^2+7$ ?

Comment: @Lærne The task is to prove $3\mid a(2a^2+7)$, not $3\mid a(a^2+7)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=2b+1$. Then $a^2+3=4b^2+4b+4$ and $a^2+7=4b^2+4b+8$.
Both of these terms are divisible by 4, so $(a^2+3)(a^2+7)=16(b^2+b+1)(b^2+b+2)$.

Now note that exactly one of $b^2+b+1$ and $b^2+b+2$ must be even since they have difference one (in fact it must be the second term) so therefore

$(a^2+3)(a^2+7)=32(b^2+b+1)\dfrac{b^2+b+2}{2}$, so 32| $(a^2+3)(a^2+7)$.

For the second part, consider the statement modulo 3.

If a=0 mod 3, then we are done (a=0 mod 3 means 3|a so in particular divides any multiple).
Otherwise $a^2=1$ mod 3, hence $2a^2+7 = 2+1=0$ mod 3 so 3 divides the second factor and we're done.

Comment: I don't understand why otherwise we have a^2 ≡ 1 (mod 3). If a^2 ≠ 3k , then could it also be that a^2 ≡ 2 (mod 3) or a^2 ≡ 3 (mod3) ?

Comment: I'm assuming that $a \neq 3k$ else it is 0 mod 3. If $a=3k+1$, then $a^2=9k^2+6k+1=3(3k^2+2k)+1$ so is 1 mod 3 and if $a=3k+2$ then $a^2=9k^2+12k+4=3(3k^2+4k+1)+1$ so is 1 mod 3. So either way, either $a=0$ mod 3 or $a^2=1$ mod 3

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, that is, $3 \, | \, a(2a^2 + 7)$:

We have that $a^3 \equiv a \pmod{3}$, by Fermat. Hence $2a^3 + 7a \equiv 2a + 7a \pmod{3}$.

But $2a + 7a \equiv 9a \equiv 0\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Why do we have that a cubed is congruent to a mod 3?

Comment: By Fermat... :-)